# Convert Selected excel cells into PDF

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a Excel which i want to save only a certain cells as pdf.

In General Scenario, It can be done through saving the pdf using the selection option.By this way i can get the selected part as pdf.

But the catch is I want other Worksheets also as a part of the selected PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1) Select a range on each sheet, choose **Print Areas** => **Set Print Area**

2) **File** => **Save & Send** => **Create PDF/XPS Document** *(a dialog is displayed)*

3) Choose **Options...** button *(a dialog is displayed)*

4) In *Publish What* group, choose **Entire Workbook** and **uncheck** "Ignore print areas" => **OK** *(current dialog is closed)*

5) Click **Publish** button to export document *(current dialog is closed)*

Good luck!